# video4linux recording and viewing at same time

Tags: video

I need an application for recording a video, while simultaneously viewing it, from my TV capture card. I've tried tvtime, but it doesn't support recording. xawtv works, just about but often crashes or refuses to record. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried VLC? It can capture a stream and save it to a file or a network stream. Open VLC and select "Open capture device" from the "Media" menu. Give it a try.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can it do both at once? I did try it... but I could only get it either recording or displaying, not both.

Comment: Have a look for yourself, I chose "desktop" cause I dont have a real capture device on this computer but I'll assume it works and you wont have any further problems ;)

Comment: I just realised in my infinite genius I wrote displayed and viewing at the same time. I meant recording and viewing at the same time. I'll try VLC next time I need to do this.

Comment: Sniff, I feel so ashamed that the images came from my WindowsXP work computer :P Well anyways I hope this works for what you want and if it doesn't say so we can find another "solution"!

Comment: XP is the only Windows I'll use. VLC is cross platform so it shouldn't matter too much.

Comment: It doesn't, I also tested this on my virtual fedora box ;)

Comment: If it works out that this is a good solution for what you need mark it "accepted" next time you login plz. gl!

Comment: I'll mark it accepted if it works. :)

Comment: Wouldn't ask for more!

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: It's too fast, or too slow, or the speed varies. Whatever I try, it does not play at normal speed after recording. Any idea why?

Comment: Have you tried changing the encoding and disabling compiz and the anything that might interfere?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to do that - but eventually I found that gtkrecordmydesktop with encoding on the fly *disabled* keeps the right speed, but no idea why that is the only program capable of doing so.

Comment: What are you using as a source? Are you recording your desktop or are you telling VLC to recorde right out of the source? Recording your desktop with VLC is not nice but never had problems getting things right out the source directly (tv cards, etc). Shame if it doesnt work with you, I would feel so imba! ;) Anyways, gl and if something else comes up just say!